# Double Drop Down - w/ OVERFLOW 3rd Column List for Subs

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I have been trying to figure out how to have an "overflow" column for my double drop down menu. (All CSS)
 I am working with the **"Entertainment"** Link *ONLY*
 Here is the Live EXAMPLE : http://www.glustik.com/dustreeproductions/company.php 
 The **"Solos | Duos | Trios"** is *clearly* too long and is an issue. I am attempting to make any listed items after 10 or so "overflow" to an additional column (not yet shown). 
 Any Help or Suggestions on how this might be done would be extremely helpful and always appreciated. 
 Thank Guys (and Ladys) 
 Here is my CSS for the Navigation :

```
#nav {
font-family: arial, sans-serif;
position: relative;
width: 990px;
height:60px;
font-size:0.95em;
color:#999;}

#nav ul li {
float: left;
position: relative;
list-style-type: none;}

#nav ul li a {
text-align: center;
height:60px;
display:block;
text-decoration:none;
color:#999;
text-indent:-9999px;}

#nav #company a  {
    background:url(http://glustik.com/dustreeproductions/images/navigation/nav-company.png) no-repeat;
    display:block;
    text-decoration:none;
    width:103px;
    margin:20px 27px 0 20px;
    height:20px;}
    #nav #company:hover > a {
    background-position:0 -20px;}
    #nav #company a:active {
    background-position:0 -40px;}
    body#body_company #company a {
    background-position:0 -40px;}

#nav #entertainment a  {
    background:url(http://glustik.com/dustreeproductions/images/navigation/nav-entertainment.png) no-repeat;
    display:block;
    text-decoration:none;
    width:168px;
    margin:20px 27px 0 0;
    height:20px;}
    #nav #entertainment:hover > a {
    background-position:0 -20px;}
    #nav #entertainment a:active {
    background-position:0 -40px;}
    body#body_entertainment #entertainment a {
    background-position:0 -40px;}

#nav #video a  {
    background:url(http://glustik.com/dustreeproductions/images/navigation/nav-video.png) no-repeat;
    display:block;
    text-decoration:none;
    width:63px;
    margin:20px 27px 0 0;
    height:20px;}
    #nav #video:hover > a {
    background-position:0 -20px;}
    #nav #video a:active {
    background-position:0 -40px;}
    body#body_video #video a {
    background-position:0 -40px;}

#nav #studio a  {
    background:url(http://glustik.com/dustreeproductions/images/navigation/nav-studio.png) no-repeat;
    display:block;
    text-decoration:none;
    width:76px;
    margin:20px 27px 0 0;
    height:20px;}
    #nav #studio:hover > a {
    background-position:0 -20px;}
    #nav #studio a:active {
    background-position:0 -40px;}
    body#body_studio #studio a {
    background-position:0 -40px;}

#nav #liveAudio a  {
    background:url(http://glustik.com/dustreeproductions/images/navigation/nav-live.png) no-repeat;
    display:block;
    text-decoration:none;
    width:113px;
    margin:20px 27px 0 0;
    height:20px;}
    #nav #liveAudio:hover > a {
    background-position:0 -20px;}
    #nav #liveAudio a:active {
    background-position:0 -40px;}
    body#body_live #liveAudio a {
    background-position:0 -40px;}

#nav #eventPlanning a  {
    background:url(http://glustik.com/dustreeproductions/images/navigation/nav-events.png) no-repeat;
    display:block;
    text-decoration:none;
    width:172px;
    margin:20px 27px 0 0;
    height:20px;}
    #nav #eventPlanning:hover > a {
    background-position:0 -20px;}
    #nav #eventPlanning a:active {
    background-position:0 -40px;}
    body#body_event #eventPlanning a {
    background-position:0 -40px;}

#nav #contact a  {
    background:url(http://glustik.com/dustreeproductions/images/navigation/nav-contact.png) no-repeat;
    display:block;
    text-decoration:none;
    width:93px;
    margin:20px 12px 0 0;
    height:20px;}
    #nav #contact:hover > a {
    background-position:0 -20px;}
    #nav #contact a:active {
    background-position:0 -40px;}
    body#body_contact #contact a {
    background-position:0 -40px;}

#nav ul li ul {display: none}

#nav ul li:hover ul#sub {
display: block;
position: absolute;
margin:0 0 0 0;
z-index:15;}

#nav ul li:hover ul#sub li a {
display:block;
background:#e6e6e6;
color:#d89656;
padding:5px 10px 0px 10px;
height:25px;
width:265px;
text-align: left;
text-indent:0px;
border-right: none;
margin: 0 0;}

#nav ul li:hover ul#sub li a:hover {
background:#CCC;
color:#d89656;}

#nav > li ul li:hover ul {
    position:absolute;
    left:280px;
    top:0;
    display:block;
    width:305px;
    padding:0px 10px 0px 5px;}

#country > ul {margin:-30px 0 0 0;}
#dance > ul {margin:-60px 0 0 0;}
#dj > ul {margin:-90px 0 0 0;}
#karaoke > ul {margin:-120px 0 0 0;}
#productionShows > ul {margin:-150px 0 0 0;}
#rockabilly > ul {margin:-180px 0 0 0;}
#solos > ul {margin:-210px 0 0 0;}
```

Comment: Smaller font, less padding OR filter them into two columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not target the offending `ul` using the existing ID's and make it wider?

```
 #solos ul{width: 575px;}
```

As you have already floated the `li`'s left, when you expand the width of the `ul` to be able to fit two `li`'s, they will wrap in lines of two.

You also need to change this rule:

```
#nav > li ul li:hover ul {
    display: block;
    left: 280px;
    padding: 0 10px 0 5px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 305px; /* Delete this */
}
```

Comment: I have tried that and it does not seem to be working. Anyone else testing this?

Comment: @varazi: I have looked at your code closer and have updated my answer for you.